# Pseudocode à la Scala

Tags: scala, pseudocode

Are there any good examples of a Scala'ish style for writing [pseudo-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) which can be used to specify algorithms in an abstract way. E.g. leaving out implied or unnecessary types?

My idea is to describe capabilities with structural type aliases, e.g.

```
type Vertex = {
  val preLabel
  val postLabel
}
```

but also intuitively I would use `if ... then ... else` instead of `if (...) ... else ...`

Comment: Yes, it is named oCaml ;-)

Comment: The best executable pseudo-code is still Python. :)

Comment: @EmilIvanov how would you express types in Python? I can see the point of using indentation instead of curly braces for pseudo code.

Comment: @EmilIvanov You're a bot registered on the `pseudocode` tag, right?

Comment: @ziggystar: Yes, I am. I mean... The best executable pseudo-code is still Python. :)